# Javafx tableview edit method not call cellfactory

Tags: javafx, tableview, edit, tablecell

I try set edit cell on run program. Set table editable, cellfactory and other. 
I can edit the cell, when clicked with the mouse. But the call `edit()` method of `TableView` does not create Textfield.

What have I missed?

```
public class Main extends Application {

    TableView <TestClass> tableView;
    TableColumn <TestClass, String>  stringColumn;
    TableColumn <TestClass, String> editColumn;
    ObservableList<TestClass> items;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        makeTestData();

        tableView = new TableView();
        tableView.setEditable(true);
        stringColumn = new TableColumn<>("Col1");
        editColumn = new TableColumn<>("Col2");
        tableView.getColumns().addAll(stringColumn, editColumn);
        stringColumn.setCellValueFactory(cell -> cell.getValue().stringProperty());
        editColumn.setCellValueFactory(cell -> cell.getValue().editProperty());
        editColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<TestClass>forTableColumn());
        tableView.setItems(items);

        tableView.getSelectionModel().select(1);
        tableView.getSelectionModel().focus(1);
        tableView.edit(1, editColumn);  // !!! not create textfield ???

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setCenter(tableView);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void makeTestData(){
        items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new TestClass("str1", "edit1"),
                new TestClass("str2", "edit2"),
                new TestClass("str3", "edit3")
        );
    }

    public class TestClass{
        StringProperty string = new SimpleStringProperty();
        StringProperty edit = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public TestClass() {}
        public TestClass(String string, String edit) {
            this.string = new SimpleStringProperty(string);
            this.edit = new SimpleStringProperty(edit);
        }
        public String getString() { return string.get();}
        public StringProperty stringProperty() { return string; }
        public void setString(String string) { this.string.set(string);}
        public String getEdit() { return edit.get();}
        public StringProperty editProperty() { return edit;}
        public void setEdit(String edit) { this.edit.set(edit);}
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Double-clicking on a item in the edit column makes the textfield appear.

Comment: Confirmed. Using a similar set-up, invoking tableview.edit(row, column) did fail to call up the editable textfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes im also getting this problem. the way i solved it is by putting the edit method call inside another fx thread.

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    tableView.edit(row, editColumn);
});
```